# How to test if a string has only spaces in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea, space

I have a textarea and I need to test if the user put a text like "                        ", or only spaces in it or only " ", I can't accept only spaces, but I can accept "         Hi    !!". How can I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Just trim it and the length will be 0 if it is all spaces.

```
strname.trim().length == 0
```

Comment: This way? $(this).trim().length > 0
But it returned an error, trim needs an argument, shouldn't it be 
trim($(this)).length > 0
?

Comment: trim is a method of a string.  Is $(this) a string?  Maybe $(this).toString().trim().length depending on the type of this. Or $(this).value.

Comment: Looking at your question, if $(this) is a textarea, you probably want $(this).value.

Answer (score 1):

You check it like this: [demo on JSexample](http://www.jsexample.com/#DwZwxgTglgDgLgPgFAAI0oG4EMIrgUwA84UBeFAcnWvQtXSgDMAKA4gOgFss4wALZgHoAegB0QAKgAkggJSyA3vRoosAG3wQ4zCmAD2AOzhYoBkCkNqAnihAwsYfCACEFWcpQBfJMEHho8AhAAA=)

```
<script>
    var text = '          '
    if(text.match(/^\s*$/)){
        alert('contains only spaces!')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, some browsers don't support trim() function. I'd use like this:

```
if (!!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
    alert('only spaces')
}
```